# PHP $_POST is empty when posting via Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm working on a CodeIgniter web app, and I seem to have run into a very peculiar problem when posting an image data URL as part of an an ajax request. The data URI is obtained using a jQuery plugin called [JCrop](http://deepliquid.com/content/Jcrop.html). The peculiarity is that the following code works just fine on localhost, but the POST body is mysteriously empty when I run the same code on a shared hosting server.

**The ajax**:

```
$('#save-settings').click(function() {
    var user = {
        id: $('#id').val(),
        email: $('#email').val(),
        phone: $('#phone').val(),
        settings: {
            profile_pic: $('#image_output').attr('src') //returns a really long data URI string, eg. data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAMgAAADICAY....
            notifications: false
        }
    };

    $.ajax({
        url: '/api/save_settings',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
            type: 'SETTINGS_USER',
            settings: JSON.stringify(user),
        },
        success: function(response) {
            console.log(response);
        },
    });
});
```

**The PHP**:

```
public function save_settings() {
    try {
        /****************************************
        * The problem lies below. It runs fine
        * on localhost, but generates an error
        * "Notice: Undefined index type" on the
        * shared hosting environment
        ****************************************/
        $type = $_POST['type']; //Not sure why it's undefined

        error_log(print_r($_POST, true)); //<--- prints an empty array in the production environment, but correctly prints  the indexes on localhost
        if($type == "SETTINGS_ADMIN") {
            //do admin related stuff
        } else if($type == "SETTINGS_USER") {
            //do user related stuff
            //use GD related functions to create and save jpeg image from data URI string
        }
    } catch(Exception $e) {
        error_log("Something went wrong");
    }
}
```

Looking at the Firebug console, it shows that the `type` variable is set, but somehow the stringified version of `settings` is missing from the `Parameters` section, although it shows under `Source`. Also, Firebug reports that the POSTed request size is ~150KB (most of it is the really long data URI string).

[image: firebug console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jXHsa.png)

Since this works fine on localost, I tried comparing some crucial php.ini settings like `post_max_size`, `upload_max_filesize` and `max_input_vars`, and they're pretty high at 8M, 16M and 1000 respectively.

The only way to get the ajax request to work on the shared hosting environment is to remove the really long data URI string from the JS object. I'm not sure what's preventing the code from working on the production environment also, and I've been going in circles over this for over 6 hours now!

**EDIT**: In trying a few things, I tried wrapping the above PHP code in an `if/else` block to test for the type of HTTP method being sent. In the dev environment, `if($this->input->server('REQUEST_METHOD') === 'POST')` returns true, but in the production environment, the `else` block executes and logs the HTTP request as `GET` (???). Is it possible that the server is stripping out the request for some reason?

Comment: Just to rule out size issues, does it work when you post a smaller value (like 10 bytes) in 'settings'? Also, you talked about a post body being empty, but in the image it isn't. Is this deliberate? What happens if you log or show `JSON.stringify(user)` before posting it. Does it contain a value? It's helpful to know whether this problem is client side or server side.

Comment: It could be that the content length is too long. This would be a setting on the server so you would want to contact your host.

Comment: @GolezTrol: I log the data to the console before posting, and the data exists (and it works in the dev environment anyway). I just changed the value of `settings.profile_pic` to a `xxxx`, and sure enough, it posts correctly. I have a feeling it might be a server side setting, but not sure which one.  

@kel: Doesn't `post_max_size` deal with the content length? I calculated the string length of the data URI, and it is at ~145KB, and the remaining 5KB is taken up by other variables, which makes the content length ~150KB, which is well under the 8M setting...

Comment: Does it also exist on production environment, that's the question. The whole thing works on dev, so of course it works there.

Comment: Just verified, yes it exists.

Comment: @GolezTrol I've tried sending varying lengths of data, from 21,934 bytes (the smallest possible with the test image I'm using, which is 4px * 4px long) to 148,722 bytes, the maximum possible with the test image. Both work in the test env, but as my recent edit points out, the server thinks it's a `GET` request instead of `POST`.